# How to escape absolute URI?

Tags: javascript

In the script: `http://theip.com/something/index.php

I have the following javascript URI:

```
var uri = '/something/script.php?=' + someDynamicValue
```

That I pass to a function "loadHTML(url, div)"

`someDynamicValue` can contain spaces and other symbols which make JQuery crash with `$.load()`.

So, I try to encode uri:

```
$('#'+div).load(encodeURIComponent(uri));
```

And gives

```
http://theip.com/something/%2Fsomething%2Fscript.php%3Fq%3D?_=1399924421585
```

That is, duplicating the /something (which should be an absolute URL so it should go to `http://ip.com/something/script.php`)

Now if I do the following:

```
$('#'+div).load(encodeURIComponent(uri).replace(/%2F/g,'/'));
```

I get a "good" url but gives 404 Error:

```
http://theip.com/something/script.php%3Fq%3D?_=1399923477529
```

So I guess it is taking `script.php%3Fq%3D?_=1399923477529` as a literal script name, maybe.

How can I fix it? (Encode the rest of the URL).

Thanks!

Comment: Escape the individual URI components *as/where* it is constructed - "component" != "full".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to encode the one part that isn't already properly URI encoded:

```
var uri = '/something/script.php?foo=' + encodeURIComponent(someDynamicValue)
$('#'+div).load(uri);
```

Comment: Yes, forgot to say that the URL comes in a piece in a function arg

Comment: @Jorge: Could you edit your question to include that information with an example of the format that the data comes in?  If so, I can update my answer to be more helpful to you.